# Laravel query returns column not found

Tags: php, laravel

I want to get list of products **if they are not exist in my collection**. But it returns column not found.

#### Error

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '1' in 'on clause' (SQL: select * from `products` inner join `collection_products` on `collection_products`.`collection_id` = `1` and `collection_products`.`product_id` != products.id where `products`.`status` = active)
```

## Code

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $collection = Collection::findOrFail($id);
        $products = DB::table('products')
        ->where('products.status', 'active')
        ->join('collection_products', function ($join) use($id) {
            $join->on('collection_products.collection_id', '=', $id)
            ->where('collection_products.product_id', '!=', 'products.id');
        })
        ->get();
        return view('admin.collections.edit', compact('collection', 'products'));
}
```

## Screenshot

`collection_products Table`

[image: one]

## Logic

By query above I should get all products with status of active, except products with id's of `3, 4, 20` because they are already signed to this collection.

Any idea?

Comment: which column is not found ?

Comment: @SagarGautam `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '1' in 'on clause' (SQL: select * from `products` inner join `collection_products` on `collection_products`.`collection_id` = `1` and `collection_products`.`product_id` != products.id where `products`.`status` = active)`

Comment: I guess this line ```$join->on('collection_products.collection_id', '=', $id)``` is wrong. You can not join on value. Your ```$id``` is value not column, Thats`s why its searching for column name as ```$id```s value.

Comment: It's because join on needs column not a variable $id

Comment: @SagarGautam i used `$id` to separate this collection with others, what you suggest then?

Comment: @PrashantDeshmukh..... suggestion?

Comment: @mafortis You have to use column name there. To make query work and you can ```$id``` in where clause to filter out you query result.

Comment: add where clause

Comment: @SagarGautam i changed `$join->on` to `$join->where` now it returns all products even signed ones.

Comment: ```whereNotIn('collection_products.product_id', [3,4,20])```. You need this condition.

Comment: @PrashantDeshmukh..... i don't have that array due to my code this array `[3,4,20]` comes with this query which currently is unable to run. By your suggestion i'm getting `Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::cleanBindings() must be of the type array, string given`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query or use it as reference.

```
$product = DB::table('products')
                  ->join('collection_products','collection_products.product_id','!=','products.id')
                  ->where('products.status', 'active')
                  ->where('collection_products.product_id', '!=', 'products.id')
                  ->where('collection_products.collection_id', '=', $id)
                  ->get();
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'product.id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select * from `products` inner join `collection_products` on `collection_products`.`product_id` != `product`.`id` where `products`.`status` = active and `collection_products`.`product_id` != products.id and `collection_products`.`collection_id` = 5)

Comment: @mafortis Typo. It was ```'product.id``` earlier, now changed it to ```'products.id```. Check now.